# Using XSLT in a concise way to modify XML elements

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I have the xml file that I totally didn't get from somewhere else

```
<bookstore>
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>
      <name>Plato</name>
    </author>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

As a test, I want to modify all the prices to the nonsense "i win"

And so I wrote the following XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match = "/bookstore/book/price">
        <price>i win</price>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I then use the following vb.net code to parse it

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xslt = New XslCompiledTransform
        dim curDir = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory
        xslt.Load(curDir & "\testtransform.xsl")
        xslt.Transform(curDir & "\testinv2.xml",curDir & "\outinv.xml")
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I ran this, outinv.xml contained the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  
    The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin
    
      Benjamin
      Franklin
    
    <price>i win</price>
  
  
    The Confidence Man
    
      Herman
      Melville
    
    <price>i win</price>
  
  
    The Gorgias
    
      Plato
    
    <price>i win</price>
```

So essentially it thanos snapped all the tags that weren't those specific price tags, which I think makes sense. My question is whether there is a way through xslt to modify those tags and keep everything else the same, without having to make templates for every single possible tag that I expect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you can declare `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`. You would need to use Saxon for XSLT 3, Microsoft doesn't support it.

For an XSLT 1.0 processor you would need to add "the identity transformation template" to your code:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that I must have it at the end, not the top?

Comment: @gist076923, the order of templates can matter but for the one you have and the one I suggested to add it doesn't matter whether you add it before or after the template you have.

Comment: @gist076923 The order of the templates does not matter (in this case). The priority of the *identity transform* template is -0.5. The priority of your existing template is 0.5: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#conflict

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - **not XSLT** method

The data,

```
    Dim ze As XElement
    ze = XElement.Load(path)
    'for test use literal
    ze = <bookstore>
             <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
                 <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
                 <author>
                     <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
                     <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
                 </author>
                 <price>8.99</price>
             </book>
             <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
                 <title>The Confidence Man</title>
                 <author>
                     <first-name>Herman</first-name>
                     <last-name>Melville</last-name>
                 </author>
                 <price>11.99</price>
             </book>
             <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
                 <title>The Gorgias</title>
                 <author>
                     <name>Plato</name>
                 </author>
                 <price>9.99</price>
             </book>
         </bookstore>
```

The code to change price,

```
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From el In ze.<book>.<price> Select el
    For Each el As XElement In ie
        el.Value = "SOME VALUE"
    Next
```

Comment: I wasn't aware linq had that sort of tag reference syntax. That looks useful

Comment: This honestly looks like the/a solution to the big problem I wanted to solve